# sending emails with sendgrid from firestore

Tags: typescript, firebase, sendgrid

I am currently working on a website. There is a section that represents "Contact Directly," this will send an email with the information that the person puts in the text boxes. I have created a firebase function succesfully, and signed up for SendGrid.

This is my functions page where i created the function

```
 import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
 import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

 admin.initializeApp();


 import * as sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';

 const API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key;
 sgMail.setApiKey(API_KEY);


 exports.newContact = functions.firestore.document('Data/{DataID}')
    .onCreate((event) =>{
   
        const msg = {
            to: 'blankEmail@email.com',
            from: 'blankEmail@email.com',
            subject: 'hello',
            html: 'hey there you why is this function not freaking working'
        }

        return sgMail.send(msg);

    });
```

I have this set up in my index.TS file which uploads the functions to firebase.

I am able to get this function to fire on the server but it always return with "error"

This is the error that i always get when i add a new document

newContact:

Error: Forbidden at node_modules/@sendgrid/client/src/classes/client.js:146:29 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

I have looked online for some solutions. Some people said i had to create a verified sender within sendgrid which i did but then i still get this error when triggering the function.

Comment: If you look at the [source code for that error](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/main/packages/client/src/classes/client.js#L146), it's throwing the response when SendGrid returns a status code of `>=400`. You can use that to find out more details about the error by chaining a catch handler: `sgMail.send(msg).catch(errorRes => { /* do something */ })` (e.g. you should also log `errorRes.data` / `errorRes.status` / `errorRes.headers`)

Comment: If the error is "Forbidden" then it is likely something to do with your API key. Can you check that the API key is definitely being loaded from the config. Can you also check that the API key has permission to send emails?

Comment: @philnash how do i check that the key is loading in properly

Comment: Can you log out the API Key to see if is present and correct?

Comment: all good fixed it @phi

Comment: Oh cool! Do you want to add an answer so that other people see what went wrong and how to fix it?